# WP Advanced Search: Default value for taxonomy field

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using a WP Advanced Search to search for custom posts. It contains 4 fields, one to search the post's title, two other to limit search results to specific meta data, and another one to limit results to a specific custom taxonomy:

```
[...]
$args['fields'][] = array('type' => 'taxonomy',
'label' => __('Discipline:', CORE_THEME_NAME),
'taxonomy' => 'course-discipline',
'format' => 'select',
'class' => 'searchselect',
'operator' => 'IN');
[...]
```

What I want to do now, is to add an empty default selection option for the taxonomy at the top. Does anyone know how to do that in the most simple way?

Answer (score 0):

Exemplo!

```
$args['fields'][] = array(
    'allow_null' => 'Mês',
    'type' => 'date',
    'date_type' => 'month',
    'format' => 'select',
);
```

Comment: While your post answers to the question it's always better to explain why your solution should work and it could be much more helpful for future users searching for the same problem.